# Able to zip files in MSBuild...How to zip folders?

Tags: msbuild

I have configured MSBuild to zip all of the files in my bin directory upon compilation using MSBuild.Community.Tasks.  However, it is not zipping the folders in my bin directory.

How do I configure MSBuild to zip my folders as well?

Here is the configuration:

```
<Target Name="Zip">
  <CreateItem Include="bin\*">
    <Output ItemName="ZipFiles" TaskParameter="Include" />
  </CreateItem>
  <Zip ZipFileName="zip\WebBinder.zip" WorkingDirectory="bin" Files="@(ZipFiles)" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Include of your CreateItem to have "bin\**\*" to recurse into the directories.

```
<CreateItem Include="bin\**\*">
```